# data being passed from controller, is it encoded?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to ask in MVC3+;  data passed from controller in form of modle or viewbag is the data encoded by default or I do have to ?

Comment: encoded how?  UrlEncoded?

Comment: @ps2goat html encoded please ?

Answer (score 1):

MVC proactively tries to encode values to prevent cross-site scripting.

```
 @* This is HTML Encoded *@
 @Model.Value 

 @* This value is not encoded *@
 @Html.Raw(Model.Value)  

 @* The URL gets URL Encoded *@
 <a href="@Url" />
```

This Razor code

```
 @ {
  bool disabled = false;
  bool readonly = true; 
  string className = null;
 }
 <input type="text" disabled="@disabled" readonly="@readonly" class="@className" />
```

Actually produces this output

```
 <input type="text" readonly="readonly" />
```

A value of **null** or **false** causes the Razor view engine to not render the attribute at all.

If you did want something like this *data-soldout="false"* then you need to do:

```
 data-soldout="@Html.Raw(isSoldout)" or data-soldout="@isSoldout.ToString()"
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean HTML encoded? They're not, no.

This means that if you have a string property that contains the value `"<b>some text</b>"` then the property contents is exactly that.

If, however, you try to print this output to the View with `@MyProperty` then, by default, the string **will** be HTML-encoded by MVC. So the output would become `&lt;some text&gt;`.

You can escape this by using `@Html.Raw(MyProperty)`.

Remember that the term 'encoded' is a bit vague. Try to be specific with what encoding you're referring to.

Comment: This is true, unless MyProperty happens to implement IHtmlString... in which case it would not be automatically encoded.  IHtmlString tells the razor view engine that you've already encoded the string.  That's why all of the HTML Helper methods return IHtmlString.